# Is it possible to update iPhone4  to a provider-neutral OS so WiFi hotspot can be enabled?

Tags: iphone, tethering, ipad

I want to use an original (non jailbroken) iPhone4 to access the internet with an iPad.

This should is possible using the Personal wifi hotspot included in iOS 4.3 as mentioned in [Can I use tethering to share my iPhone's connection with my iPad?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9439/tethering-ipad-to-iphone), however some providers (such as the Dutch T-mobile) have removed this feature in a localised version of the OS.

Is there a (legitimate) way to update to a "generic" iOS so I can use the Personal Hotspot to tether my iPad or is there another (legitimate) way to not have to get the 3G iPad and an extra sim card.

Please note I am in Europe, i.e. not on AT&T or Verizon

Comment: ?? Is this a question or a rant?

Comment: Can you please reformat what you're asking as a question?

Comment: I'm closing this question because the only part that isn't localized has already been answered. It's also hard to tell exactly what's being asked here.

Comment: @Nathan it was a question on meta how to ask a similar question. then I was told it was a question so I should ask it. When I then investigated myself after moving it here, I found out it was not to be due to t-mobile decisions. What is "Too localised" ? how many potential users needs to be affected for something not to be too localised? I could say the same about issues only affecting Verizon customers with iPads, no? Anyway I reformulated it, so can it be re-opened?

Comment: @mplungjan I suggest you re-create your question (the update to a vendor neutral OS) and add the other information (because off the tethering has been removed…) as additional information on why you want to do it. But the core of the question is your "updated" question and should be reflected in the title.

Comment: @martin: Done..

Comment: @mplungjan: I'm still not clear on what is being asked here. It reads almost as if you noting a problem and a possible solution or roadblock. Is your question asking how to do what you are stating in your first paragraph? It seems there might be a language barrier here so I we need to sort out a way to validly reopen what looks to be a potentially legitimate question.

Comment: @Philip is this better?

Comment: @mplungjan: Yes. I have re-opened the question.

Comment: Good question. Is it the OS that is localised? Or is it part of the carrier settings? I must admit I don't know enough about how this is enforced and am curious to see the answers -- even if it isn't possible -- to understand how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a carrier localized version of the OS that is installed on the iPhone. There is one iOS release image for each hardware model. What changes for each mobile network is the carrier settings, which is downloaded either OTA (iOS4+) or by iTunes when the phone is activated or connected and an update is available.

If you have the released from any carrier lock then if you move to another mobile provider supporting the tethering feature then their carrier settings will enable the preference.

Comment: Does not sound promising :( Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would help you?

Mac: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL851
Win: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL926

Comment: Ahem - possibly. I would be worried if I would brick the phone. But at least that is an answer +1

Answer (score 1):

I doubt the feature is removed from your version of the iOS. The carrier has complete control over whether or not this feature is visible on your iPhone by configuring your account with them. In my case, I am a US AT&T customer with an iPhone 4, but because I don't pay for the plan that has tethering as an option, when I go to the Settings panel, I **do not** see a preference to turn on/off tethering. My friend who is also a US AT&T customer with an iPhone 4 **and** the correct plan that allows tethering, has the phone tethering on/off option where I have none (we've compared our settings screens).

I wouldn't waste time trying to track down some non-localized version of the OS in the hopes that this feature is going to be there.

Sorry. I wish I had better news for you.